# AngularJS UI-calendar not updating events on Calendar

Tags: angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using Angular UI-Calendar to show some events on the Calendar. The events are showing fine on the Calendar. But when I update any event's details, the event's detail is actually modified, but not modified on the Calendar display(eg: start).

Initially, after I modified the event's details, I did a page reload to display modified changes and it worked too.In that method, I had empty `$scope.events = [];` array, which I filled after retrieving entries from DB.

But now, I want to avoid that page reload. So, once the event's details are modified from modal window, I clear the contents of `$scope.events` array using `$scope.events = [];` and then using API call, I fill the new events again in `$scope.events` array. This is working fine as the List view shows the modified events details. But the Calendar itself shows old entries. e.g if I change `start` from 11 April to 13 April, the calendar shows event on 11 April whereas List views shows the modified data i.e 13 April. Using Page reload, corrects this i.e event is shown on modified date(13 April).

How can I ensure that the event is modified on Calendar too without a Page reload ?

I tried `calendar.fullCalendar('render');` after fetching new entries from DB, but it does not solve the Problem.

Here are some codes :

Initially I did this to send data to DB and then did a page reload to retrieve updated data.
`$http.put(url,senddata).success(function(data){$window.location.reload();});`

Now I want to avoid the page reload, so I did

```
        $http.put(url,senddata).success(function(data){//$window.location.reload();//sends modified data to server
        $scope.events = [];  //clear events array

   $http.get(url2).success(function(data){  //fetch new events from server, and push in array
  $scope.schedule = data;
          for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
          {
            $scope.events.push({
      idx: data[i].idx,
      title: data[i].title,
      description : data[i].description,
      allDay: false,
      start: new Date(data[i].start), 
      end:  new Date(data[i].end),

      });


     calendar.fullCalendar('render'); //Tried even this, didn't work



          }

        });
```

Above code pushes modified event in `event` array as visible in List view, but calendar still shows old event until page is reloaded.

Answer (score 23):

Try maintaining the same array instance.

Instead of doing:

`$scope.events = []`

Try:

`$scope.events.slice(0, $scope.events.length);`

Then when your server request comes back, add each item individually to the existing array:

`for(var i = 0; i < newEvents.length; ++i) {
  $scope.events.push(newEvents[i]);
}`

The reason I suggest this is because what you're describing sounds like the calendar might be holding onto the old list of events.  The calendar might not know to update its reference, so instead, let it keep the same reference but change the contents of the array.

Comment: This is the perfect answer and right way to fix the issue. @Studio4Development You made my day.

Comment: Thanks @KishoreRelangi - I don't even remember the details, but glad it helped!

Comment: To explain the answer further.
if you are storing eventsources in an array which is being watched (reference of the array) by the directive and refreshes the calender whenever the variable changed.

if you write code like 
    $scope.events = [];  to clear the events, Your are creating a new Array (means new reference) and assigning it to $scope.events. But the watcher is watching the earlier reference.
    $scope.events.slice(0, $scope.events.length); is a clever way to clear the array without changing the reference which is being watched by the directive.

Comment: See @Emeka's answer below if you want to clear the array - you should be using splice instead of slice

Comment: @KishoreRelangi, how can I change $scope.events = [] to that without get an undifined error ? I'm splicing an uninitialized array

Comment: @user3550498 initialize it in controller.

Comment: @KishoreRelangi How do you mean initialize it in the controller? All this is being done in the same controller.
you cant .slice() an undefined. 
Where does `$scope.events.slice(0, $scope.events.length);` go in relation to the addEvent() function?

Answer (score 18):

Just a quick correction to Studio4Development's answer. You should use "splice" not "slice". Slice returns the trimmed array. What we want to do is actually alter the original array. So you can use:

```
$scope.events.splice(0, $scope.events.length)
```

and to add new events:

```
$scope.events.push(newEvent)
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if you found the solution to your problem, but what worked for me was:

```
calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I fixed a similar problem on my page.

**view** (simplified, note using jade)

```
div#calendarNugget(ng-show="activeCalendar == 'Nugget'" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendarNugget" ng-model="eventSources")
div#calendarWillow(ng-show="activeCalendar == 'Willow'" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendarWillow" ng-model="eventSources2")
```

**controller**:

As per ui-calendar docs, I start with an empty array for my event sources. Ignore that I should probably rename these eventSources to something about the shop names (willow, nugget)

```
$scope.eventSources = [];
$scope.eventSources2 = [];
```

I then call a factory function that makes an http request and pulls a series of events from the DB. The events all have "title", "start", "end" properties (make sure your Date format is correct). They also have a "shop" property, which tells me which calendar to add the event to.

So after receiving the data I make two local arrays, loop through the received http data, and assign the events to those local arrays by shop. Finally, I can re-render the calendars with the proper event data **by calling addEventSource, which automatically re-renders as per the fullCalendar docs**

It looks something along the lines of this iirc:

```
function splitShiftsByShop(shifts) {

  var nuggetShifts = [];
  var willowShifts = [];

  for (var i=0; i<shifts.length; i++) {
      if (shifts[i].shop === "Nugget") {

          var nshift = {
            title : shifts[i].employee,
            start : new Date(shifts[i].start),
            end : new Date(shifts[i].end),
            allDay: false
          }

          nuggetShifts.push(nshift);

      } else if (shifts[i].shop === "Willow") {

          var wshift = {
            title : shifts[i].employee,
            start : new Date(shifts[i].start),
            end : new Date(shifts[i].end),
            allDay: false
          }

          willowShifts.push(wshift);
      }
  }

  /*render the calendars again*/
    $('#calendarNugget').fullCalendar('addEventSource', nuggetShifts);
    $('#calendarWillow').fullCalendar('addEventSource', willowShifts);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having some similar issues where events weren't being refetched after emptying my "eventSource" array ($scope.eventSources = [$scope.completedEvents]) and repopulating it with new events.  I was able to overcome this at first by calling 'removeEvents',

```
uiCalendarConfig.calendars.calendar.fullcalendar('removeEvents')
```

This is hackish, so after further tinkering I found that events were refetched when my child array is modified,

```
$scope.completedEvents.splice(0, $scope.completedEvents.length)
```

After reviewing the source, I can see that the eventSource array is being watched, but the 'refetch' is never occurring.  furthermore, I was never able to get the following to work,

```
uiCalendarConfig.calendars.calendar.fullcalendar('refetchEvents')
```

Answer (score 1):

According to ui-calendar code, it does actually watch eventSources but never the actual individual sources. So doing a push to, let's say $scope.events ($scope.eventSources = [$scope.events]), will never trigger anything.

So push events to $scope.eventSources[0]

```
$scope.eventSources[0].splice(0, $scope.eventSources[0].length);
$scope.eventSources[0].push({
 title : title,
 start : start,
 end : end                    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already know Full Calendar is dependant on JQuery. Therefore, all you need to do is put an ID on your calendar like this:

```
<div id="calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" class="span8 calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div>
```

and then when ever you want to update the calendar just call:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
```

I struggled with this for some time as well and this fixed all my problems. I hope this will help you too!

Goodluck!

Comment: This is used in AngularJS so where am I supposed to put this code?
`$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')` ??

Wherever i push event in the array ?

Answer (score 0):

Although it's late response but hope it may help some. I am putting it forth step by step.

1. You will need to maintain the same event source as Studio4Development mentioned earlier.

   $scope.events //no need to reinitialize it
2. You will remove the updated event from events array like this (for last event in event array):

   $scope.events.splice($scope.events.length - 1, 1);

For event that may exist anywhere in the events array you'll need to find its index using:

```
var eventIndex = $scope.events.map(function (x) { return x.Id; }).indexOf(eventId);
```

and then you'll remove it from events array like this:

```
$scope.events.splice(eventIndex, 1);
```

3. Next you'll fetch this event from the API again like this:

   getEvent(data.Id);
4. and in the callback method you'll again add the event in events array:

   var getSingleEventSuccessCallback = function (event) {
           $scope.events.push(event);
       };

Answer (score 0):

Was stuck on this for a while. 
What seems to be working for me turned out to be quite simple

I fetch my calendar from google and run an event formatter function. In this I define a new array and at the end of the function I set my eventSource equal to the new array. Then I call `$scope.$apply`

```
    x = []
    for e in events
      x.push(
        title: e.summary
        etc...
      )
    $scope.eventSource = x
    $scope.$apply()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me.

```
function flushEvents()
{
    $scope.events.splice(0,$scope.events.length);

    for(var i=0; i<$scope.events.length; i++)
    {
        $scope.events.splice(i,1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it helped me:

```
$(id_your_div).fullCalendar('removeEvents'); 
$(id_your_div).fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at ["How do I write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).