# AngularJS UI-calendar holding reference to old events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar (angular-ui-calendar) in an AngularJS application. I am passing events using an EventSources array: `$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];` with `$scope.events` being generated and updated by the controller. My trouble is whenever I update `$scope.events`, FullCalendar seems to hold on to references to the old events.

in index.html:

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar">
```

My updateEvents function looks like this:

```
public updateEvents(newEvents) {
    // remove old events
    $scope.events.splice(0, $scope.events.length);

    // add new events using push
    for (var i = 0; i < newEvents.length; i++) {
        $scope.events.push(newEvents[i]);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the above function doesn't get rid of the old events unless I make an explicit call to refetch events from `EventSources`:

```
$scope.myCalendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

I found a similar question ([AngularJS UI-calendar not updating events on Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006464/angularjs-ui-calendar-not-updating-events-on-calendar)), and Studio4Development's answer seems the most relevant. However, I think I am maintaining the same array instance by using push and splice.

Comment: Use a function for eventSource or events instead and then refetchEvents will work

Comment: @RichardHermanson Would it be possible to do it without calling refetchEvents? I'm having trouble understanding how (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/) rerenders consistently but mine doesn't.

Comment: Not if the added event is on the current view. I suggest you use fullcalendar directly instead

Comment: Could you try with $scope.events.length = 0 ? Any plunkr/fiddl to check?

Comment: @MarioLevrero Thanks for the comment! I started with $scope.events.length = 0 and that didn't fix it, but I managed to find out the root cause. It turned out that I installed (bower does so by default) an old version of angular-ui-calendar, which does not support fullCalendar v2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to figure out why this was happening by tracing the library code, only to realize that the angular-ui-calendar I installed using bower was outdated. For some reason, bower installs version `0.8.1` by default, while `0.9.0-beta.1` is required for compatibility with fullCalendar v2. I wasn't able to reproduce this issue in plnkr because plnkr provides fullCalendar 1.6 by default, which is compatible with older versions of angular-ui-calendar.

In particular, the function

```
eventsWatcher.onRemoved = function(event) {
      scope.calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(e) { 
          return e === event; 
      });
};
```

got updated to

```
eventsWatcher.onRemoved = function(event) {
    scope.calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(e) { 
        return e._id === event._id;
    });
};
```

The old function would pass fullCalendar a filter that doesn't match anything, due to the fact that fulLCalendar v2 adds a few fields to each event (a momentJS object, for example).

TL; DR

angular-ui-calendar was not holding reference to old events. Instead, it was not removing events correctly. Updating to the latest beta release solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Edited events are not updated.

There is a bug in fullCalendar.js function `filterLegacyEventInstances()`. You can fix it from:

```
return legacyEventInstance.id == legacyQuery;
```

to:

```
return legacyEventInstance._id == legacyQuery;
```

and use it instead of minimize code.