# angular-ui ui-calendar not updating on changes to Event Source Object / ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I'm adding fullcalendar.js to an angular app using `angular-ui` / `ui-calendar`.
(`angularjs 1.3.10`, `fullcalendar 2.2.6`, `ui-calendar 0.9.0-beta.1`, `jQuery 2.1.3`, `moment 2.9.0` & `angular-moment 0.9.0`)

In the calendar I'm using the `dayClick` as a datepicker type function to:
- write the selected date to scope (for other uses in the app)
- update the Event Source Object `events` array with the selected date
- display the selected date (ie newly updated `event`) on the calendar

I have no problems completing the 1st two tasks, but the 3rd is not updating automatically.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar):
`An Event Sources objects needs to be created to pass into ng-model.
This object's values will be watched for changes. If a change occurs, then that specific calendar will call the appropriate fullCalendar method.`

However it doesn't seem to be updating the calendar this automatically...

Is this a bug in `ui-calendar` or am I missing something ?

Interestingly if I have the calendar in an `ng-if` tab, and toggle between the tabs, the calendar updates correctly (after the toggle).

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goredwards/y2du0yqw/) and:
- run, then select a date (notice the `events` array is updated correctly)
- toggle Tab 2 then back to Tab 1 - notice the date now displays correctly...

html looks like:

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="calendarDate" calendar="myCalendar1"></div>
```

Controller code looks like

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter, moment, uiCalendarConfig){

    $scope.calendarDate = [
        {
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'From',
                    start: '2015-01-31',
                    allDay: true,
                    rendering: 'background',
                    backgroundColor: '#f26522',
                },
            ],
        }
    ];

    $scope.setCalDate = function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            var dateFrom = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');                   // set dateFrom based on user click on calendar
            $scope.calendarDate[0].events[0].start = dateFrom;              // update Calendar event dateFrom
            $scope.dateFrom = $filter('date')(dateFrom, 'yyyy-MM-dd');;         // update $scope.dateFrom
    };

    $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendarFrom : {
            editable : false,
        aspectRatio: 2,
            header : {
                left : 'title',
                center : '',
                right : 'today prev,next'
            },
            dayClick : $scope.setCalDate,
            background: '#f26522',
        },
    };
});
```

PS had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006464/angularjs-ui-calendar-not-updating-events-on-calendar) question (which is similar) but was asked quite a few versions ago - plus the suggested solution `calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');` doesn't work since the `calendar` object is not defined - unsure what `calendar.fullCalendar` would be for my code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to be a problem with ui-calendar. I haven't been able to solve it so far. However, as a workaround, instead of updating the current event, you can create a new one: just replace `$scope.calendarDate[0].events[0].start = dateFrom;` by `$scope.calendarDate[0].events.push({title: 'From', start: selectedDate, allDay: true, rendering: 'background', backgroundColor: '#f26522'});`: http://jsfiddle.net/gidoca/kwsrnopz/.

On a side note, to access the calendar object to call the fullCalendar function, you would use $scope.myCalendar1 - ui-calendar adds it the the scope with a variable of the name given as the calendar attribute in the HTML.

Comment: thanks - yes it seems like the whole event has to be replaced, not just the date - it also works with `$scope.calendarDate[0].events = {title: 'From', start: selectedDate, allDay: true, rendering: 'background', backgroundColor: '#f26522'};`  ie both assignment or push() work, as long the entire event is replaced...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues but sorted out by two different ways.

When dynamically loaded the content through $http use uiCalendarConfig addEventSource

```
uiCalendarConfig.calendars['mycalendar'].fullCalendar('addEventSource', $scope.events);
```

Incase if calendar toggles visibility and hidden on load use refetchEvents

```
$timeout(function(){
   uiCalendarConfig.calendars['mycalendar'].fullCalendar('refetchEvents');  
})
```

$timeout holds the calendar to compile within the scope