# uiCalendar does not refresh when adding or removing events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-calendar

I can't get uiCalendar to update after changing the elements in the event source.

The calendar is defined in the template as:

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" class="span8 calendar" ng-model="EC.calendarEvents" calendar="eventsCalendar"></div>
```

When I add or remove elements from `EC.calendarEvents` the calendar doesn't update.

I've tried all of the following statements to try to get the calendar to refresh after modifying `EC.calendarEvents`:

```
uiCalendarConfig.calendars['eventsCalendar'].fullCalendar('render');
uiCalendarConfig.calendars['eventsCalendar'].fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
uiCalendarConfig.calendars['eventsCalendar'].fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

I've also tried removing and re-adding the source:

```
uiCalendarConfig.calendars['eventsCalendar'].fullCalendar('removeEvents');
uiCalendarConfig.calendars['eventsCalendar'].fullCalendar('addEventSource', $scope.EC.calendarEvents);
```

But this just causes the following error to show up in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined
```

The error is occurring in fullcalendar.js in the `normalizeEventTimes` function on line 12272.

The error line is:

```
eventProps.allDay = !(eventProps.start.hasTime() || (eventProps.end && eventProps.end.hasTime()));
```

In this post they suggest maintaining the same reference to the array and pushing/splicing events in and out: [AngularJS UI-calendar not updating events on Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006464/angularjs-ui-calendar-not-updating-events-on-calendar/28663610#28663610)

I tried this as well but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be an inconsistency in the format that ui-calendar expects to receive it's events in.

When the controller loads and I populate EC.calendarEvents, ui-calendar expects to receive an array of arrays. So the assignment looks like this:

```
$scope.EC.calendarEvents = [createCalendarEventsFromCoreEvents(coreEvents)];
```

However, whenever I want to alter `EC.calendarEvents`, it has to be an array only, not an array of arrays.

So subsequent updates to `EC.calendarEvents` look like this:

```
$scope.EC.calendarEvents = createCalendarEventsFromCoreEvents(filterEvents());
uiCalendarConfig.calendars['eventsCalendar'].fullCalendar('removeEvents');
uiCalendarConfig.calendars['eventsCalendar'].fullCalendar('addEventSource', $scope.EC.calendarEvents);
```

Note the lack of brackets `[]` around `createCalendarEventsFromCoreEvents`.